# Is it good practice to connect to the db multiple times?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using MongoDB, so I am connecting trough `MongoClient.connect`
but I have to use that, for every route where I want to work with the database.

Tried to preload it to an object, but then the changes are not visible, till the server is restarted. Right now, it's working properly, I am only a bit worried about the performance.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe correct answer is "it depends".

For a simple desktop application where your NodeJS program is the only client: sure.  A persistent connection is fine.

For an enterprise application with 100s or 1000s of concurrent users each connecting independently: no, you probably do NOT want to hold the connection open "forever".

One possible solution for the latter scenario is [Connection Pooling](https://www.compose.com/articles/connection-pooling-with-mongodb/).

Comment: I don't understand why a "new user" would not be visible until you restarted the server.  If you make a change, your client should see that change.  Perhaps you're running your application in a browser (and the browser is caching old data)? Please consider posting a new question with sample code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to connect to your DB once - when the server starts. As long as the server is running, the connection should persist. There is no reason to connect multiple times.